# getactiverange on different sheets apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets and i'm new to apps script and scripting as well. I'd like to know if it is possible to make a script or parts of it working on only one particular sheet, not on all of them.

Here's the code:

```
function setppl() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('START');


 var eventRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
 // var eventRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); it works as i need but it does it 
 on all of the sheets, not just 'START
 var eventColumn = eventRange.getLastColumn();
 var eventRow = eventRange.getLastRow();
 var currvalue = eventRange.getValue();
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

 if (eventColumn == 3) { ....
```

My guess is that this way there is no active range.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sheet.getActiveRange()` it does what it says, ie it gets the range that you are accessing somehow. This overrides the sheet selection you made with `ss.getSheetByName('START')`.

You could simply either define the range by its value (row,col,height,width or in A1 notation) or make the sheet 'START' active to force the display to show this sheet (but it won't prevent a user to go to another sheet).

Comment: So basically there is no option to assign a function or part of the script to the activerange of a sheet? Also a predefined range is not a good idea as it changes whenever modification is made in a new row.

   var sh = ss.getSheetByName("START");
   var row = sh.getLastRow();

This give me the number of rows, not the index of the current active row/cell.

Comment: Another option you could use to be sure the user goes to the right sheet is to protect the other sheet to prevent access to it

Comment: It's a no go as there are several sheets for user groups, and data is read and written into a master sheet by them.  But thanks anyway i will try to find a solution, maybe separate spreadsheets instead of sheets, that way it could work.